# PDF file preview in Telerik AsyncUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, telerik

Screenshot of Telerik Uploaded File Rendering List
[image]

Is there a way to change the normal text in Uploaded Files Rendering of Telerik UI into hyperlinks that allows user to preview uploaded pdf file  before submitting the form.

I.e., clicking hyperlinks to open pdf document in new window.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is similar to the one shown at [Preview uploaded image with RadAsyncUpload](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/upload-(async)/details/preview-uploaded-image-with-radasyncupload). Access selected file in the arguments of OnClientFileSelected event of AsyncUpload and display it in RadWindow or [pdf.js in the browser](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/building-an-asp.net-pdf-viewer-with-telerik-window-control-and-pdf-js).